# Cannot click on links in div that is floating on another div

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of problem with my website:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #ffffff;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    animation: fadein 5s;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

/* Menu Bars */

.section-1 {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    top: 20%;
 height: 60%; 
 float: left;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.section-1:hover + .menu-1 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-1 {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    top: 20%;
 height: 60%; 
 float: left;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.50);
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="navigation-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Title</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="section-1">
            <p>Menu 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-1">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, the expected behavior is that when I hover the div with the "Menu 1" text, the div with the "Link 1" link appears and that the "Link 1" link is clickable which will direct the user to another page. However, the "Link 1" hyperlink is unclickable and instead, highlights the "Menu 1" text.

How do I make it so that the "Like 1" hyperlink can be clicked?

Comment: First error: you are writting all positions to fixed. It will be attached to the viewport so you are making this wrong. Fixed maybe can be the parent, but the others needs to be position relative or absolute. You are creating contexts and z-index will not work as you expected. **Avoid fixed positioning if you don't know how it works**.

Comment: Second error is position fixed + float. This mix have no sense, because you are positioning through top and left, not float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `pointer-events:none` on `.menu-1`. If you absolutely need to keep this property, add `pointer-events:auto` to the `a` tag. However, I would suggest restructuring your code so that the menu can transition without the overlay.

Comment: Ok, so now the link works, but now whenever I hover over the link, the overlay (the red box) disappears along with the link (it is still clickable). Is it possible to have the overlay to be visible when I hover over the link?

Comment: You're going to want to change your HTML markup. Typically, it's bad practice to use the + selector on hover events, and its better and far more extensible to group elements into a containing element. Put menu 1 inside section 1 and remove the + operator. Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1zda573t/

Comment: Also, are you using the `<br />` tags for spacing? That's bad practice as well, you should use margins and padding.

Comment: Looks like your code solved the problem for me. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Ben Happy to! Remember to mark the answer as a solution so everyone can see that the problem's solved.